# Noob question - regarding images on webserver not loading when URL is typed, but do when clicked from link on index html

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, filenames, permissions, file-manager

[image]I have dabbled with html in the past and to a very small degree some CSS. 
All i am trying to do at this moment is have a website/webserver which stores one image. (The image will be retrieved by an Android game i have developed)

I have made a very simple index.html just for the sake of it really (and because after uploading my image to the server, I got the error: FORBIDDEN 404)

so long story short, there is a link on the index.html to the image url. If I load the page then click the link the image loads up and I can see the url is what I expected it to be. But if I type the URL into browser directly it doesn't display  (gives 404 FORBIDDEN) -- of course the game isn't able to retrieve it either as I have tested.

I have checked the Permissions of the files and folders. They were all on 755. But I read somewhere maybe it was better the actual files go onto 644, which is how I currently have it (so folders 755 / files 644). Neither way did it work.

Strangely, sometimes if I type the full image url INCLUDING www. at front, it sometimes loads ?!?!???

here is the link to the website if you'd like to see what i mean: 
[homepage](http://memesliders.tk)  and [directly to image files url](http://memesliders.tk/thisweek.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after much trial and error I found my problem.

Yes the links are incorrect now but that was nothing to do with it, I'd triple checked the links at the time but have tried 3 or more new domain names and hosting services.

The problem was 100% the free hosts I chose (I tried at least 4 of the top slots of Google), the all blocked the images from being retrieved by my game (i think its called hotlinking)

Anyway, I solved my issue very easily by joining: Githubpages.io

I have my content online for free and I control the URL name so its perfect.

If that wasn't an option, I guess I would have had to join a paid host after making them verify that this hotlink blocking wasnt in the T&C's

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is related to case sensitivity on a unix filesystem, as well as an incorrect file extension.

In your HTML you have the filename `thisWeek.png` however you are linking to `thisweek.jpg`, these are two different files.

Fixing the filename causes the image to load. Watch your case as well. `thisWeek.jpg` and `thisweek.jpg` are different.

View the image of the site with the chrome edits I made below:

[image]

*UPDATE:*

It appears that your 403 issue is intermittent and this is a common problem on the free host you are using, awardspace. They have file and word filtering on their servers that gets triggered by some images and words. See this link http://awfaq.awardspace.info/?The_FAQ_Supplement:Server_Error_Messages:I_get_a_403_-_forbidden_error%21

Comment: hi there, thanks for this. I had noticed this just now and changed it actually. But if you type memesliders.tk/thisweek.jpg it still loads nothing. and my game cant retrieve it

Comment: i edit my question with extra screen shot

Comment: Hmm it's loading for me as seen in the attached screenshot. The moment I corrected it, it loaded.

Comment: did you try opening it by typing full url. also in a a browser that doesnt have it cached? ...good to know it loaded for you though thanks

Comment: and its wierd like I say, sometimes if I do put WWW. infront of the full url, then the picture loads lol, but alas not in my game

Comment: it was a coincidence regarding the case-sensitive thing. Because I had tried a few different images. But I already had this problem with the cases definitely correct. I think if you click and inspect this time  you'll see what I mean. But anyway, thanks very much for trying to help me out

Comment: @SuperMegaBroBro I'm now seeing the issue intermittently. This isn't a permissions or linking issue. I think this is a file serving issue. How is this file being served? Apache? Can you post your Apache vHost config for this site? Something is intermittently failing to serve the file. There could be a number of reasons for this, but we need to know more about your server stack.

Comment: Umm i am very noob on webdesign so not sure whatt Apache means??? sorry. But the file is less than 50kb

Comment: its just a straight forward JPG on the root of my Memesliders.tk folder on my webserver (i hope that makes sense lol!!)

Comment: Apache is a web server, the application that serves the website and files. There are other possible servers. Who is your host?

Comment: ah, i just check. The host is called AwardSpace.com

Comment: tbf, the website is about an hour old. Could this be the reason??

Comment: sorry to be an absolute pain. But i put another screenshot of my host details. Im not sure if any of its relevant but its the best I can find on their website (see question again :P)

Comment: I found out the problem. It's your host. Maybe try another host for this. Answer is updated.

Comment: so in theory if I change the name to some random string it might work??

Comment: regardless your answer was superb thank you. ill report back with how i eventually fix it. Have an excellent one!!!! :P

Comment: It's a plausible theory, it's also possible it's trying to interpret the contents of the actual image and not just the filename.

Comment: ....well i tried changing it to mypic.jpg and still no joy. I guess I go back to 000webhost but they have "1 hr Sleep" per day now on free hosting :[  my game will be lucky to make £1 so I wont be getting paid hosting just yet haha. Thanks again for the sterling help dude

Comment: Right now you have `<A HREF="http://www.memesliders.tk/zxzsdsadzdczdsz.jpg"><IMG SRC="zxzsdsadzdczdsz.jpg" ALT="Home"></A>` which does not use the same link you gave for direct access: `http://memesliders.tk/thisweek.jpg`